# Filemaker pro on Ubuntu

Tags: mac, compatibility

I am seriously considering migrating to an Ubuntu OS for my small business. I currently use Filemaker Pro for my invoices and reports, and I was wondering if I could use that in an Ubuntu environment.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.openoffice.org/product/base.html it may help.
I have not taken a proper look yet.

Comment: Well I took another look and LibreOffice Base works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well one way of running filemaker in Ubuntu is by using [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

> Wine is a compatibility layer capable of running Windows applications
>   on several  operating systems, such as Linux.

Another way is using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).  VirtualBox is free software that gives you the ability to run an OS inside a virtual machine.  So you can install it under Ubuntu, and the use Windows as the guest OS.

Also you may want to look at [Glom](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/glom/)

<sup>Source: [winehq.org](http://www.winehq.org/)</sup>